# PostgreSQL transpose rows to columns dynamicaly

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

Hi Im trying to make the result of my query to align dynamically in 1 row per column please help me if this is possible

For example this is my table

```
id , names , comm    , contrib
1    samp1   randtext     9
2    samp1   randtext     2
3    samp1   randtext     3 
5    samp2   randtext     4 
6    samp2   randtext     1
```

then the result im trying to get is

```
names  comm1    comm2    comm3    contrib1  contrib2  contrib3 
samp1  randtext,randtext,randtext    9      , 2       , 3
samp2  randtext,randtext,            4      , 1       ,
```

thank you for helping out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+pivot+crosstab

Comment: please be specific .

Answer (score 0):

We can use a combination of `ROW_NUMBER` with a pivot query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY names ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM your_table
)

SELECT
    names,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN comm END) comm1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN comm END) comm2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN comm END) comm3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN contrib END) contrib1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN contrib END) contrib2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN contrib END) contrib3
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    names
ORDER BY
    names;
```

Comment: Thank you tim! . is there a way to make it more dynamic .. for example the comm and contrib will have more than 3 column depends on the length of the inserted items ?

Comment: See the  crosstab comment under your question, or look into using dynamic SQL.